# How to get max and min of generated random numbers and find the sum of the two in Eclipse

Tags: java

This is the code I have and i'm confused about how to set it up. I'm fairly new to coding so any input would help. When I execute the code I get 10 random numbers which is what I want but the max always comes out to be 10.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Question2Chapter4 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
      Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

      int max = 0;
      int counter;
      Random num = new Random();

      System.out.println("Random numbers are:");
      for (counter = 1; counter <= 10; counter++) {
        System.out.println(num.nextInt(100));

        if (max < counter) {
          max = counter;
        }   
      }
      System.out.println("Largest number is " + max);
      in.close();
   }
}
```

Here is an example of one of the outputs:

Random numbers are:
73
66
64
89
57
75
60
47
74
29
Largest number is 10

Comment: You aren't storing anything. You are checking the counter, not the value

Comment: Not bad for a first question on Stack Overflow! Small and complete code, expected and actual output. It’s questions like this one that make it easy and pleasureful to help. Welcome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not storing the random value in your `max` variable. Instead you are storing the `counter` variable which maximum value will be 10(as defined in your loop). So replace your loop code to this:

```
int number = num.nextInt(100); // store your random number
System.out.println(number);

if (max < number) {
      max = number;
}
```

If you want the minimum value add another variable and another if statement:

```
int min = 100; // before the loop
...
if (min > number) { // inside the loop and after the random number is generated
    min = number;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the input. So if I wanted to find the minimum and print that out I would just create another if loop but replace it with min correct?

Comment: See my edits. I have added what you need to get the minimum.

Comment: You should probably initialiize `min` to something greater than 0.